# Hdparm -N Problem with CHS LBA size mismatch

Tags: xubuntu, hdparm

I have been trying to use HPA to size a drive down to the size I need it to be but have run into an obstacle with CHS and LBA total sectors not matching after HPA sizing.  So I am trying to implement the -N c,h,s method in a previous answer here but have not been able to get it to work.  Is there some trick to achieving this?  My LBA total sectors are 512,000 and my CHS total sectors are 511,056 because the sectors per track is set at 63!and I need it to be 32.  So only way to solve and have them match is I somehow need to set the drive to 1000,16,32.  Any advice is appreciated!  Oh btw- this was using xubuntu with hdparm 9.60.  Maybe the issue is I need another version of hdparm?‍♂️